# Counting days excluding weekends in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to count days between two dates minus weekends in PostgreSQL. The table currently looks like:

```
file_id      date       type 
------------------------------- 
   1        6/1/20      Reply  
   1        6/5/20     Referral
   1        6/8/20      Sent 
   2        5/1/20      Reply 
   2        5/4/20     Referral 
   2        5/15/20     Reply 
   2        5/15/20    Referral 
   2        5/18/20     Sent 
   2        5/29/20     Sent
```

I need to calculate time difference between first instance of reply, first instance of referral, first instance of sent. So I am currently using the following select statement:

```
select file_id, 
   min(case when lower(type) = 'reply' then date end) as date_1,
   min(case when lower(type) = 'referral' then date end) as date_2,
   min(case when lower(type) = 'sent' then date end) as date_3
   round(extract(epoch from (date_2 - date_1))/86400, 1) as tm_1_to_2,
   round(extract(epoch from (date_3 - date_2))/86400, 1) as tm_2_to_3
```

I saw somewhere that one can `extract(dow from))` to get date difference minus weekends, but for some reason I get error saying `ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  0 : Invalid interval part value: 'DOW'` after running `extract(DOW from (date_2 - date_1))`.

Can anyone help achieving calculating days between two dates while excluding weekends?

Answer (score 1):

I would use this function:

```sql
create function days_between(date_from date, date_to date) returns integer immutable as
$$
 select count(*)::integer - 1 
   from generate_series(date_from, date_to, interval '1 day') d 
  where extract (isodow from d) between 1 and 5;
$$ language sql;
```

Example call:

```sql
select days_between('2021-03-26','2021-04-01');
-- returns 4
```